# What powers does the speaker of the House of Representatives have?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, power, speaker

What official and unofficial powers does the speaker have personally and what powers do they have that require other members’ approval?

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives